# Reducing the size of elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, size, n-gram

I've just taken over a project that maintains an elasticsearch indexes and I'm new to the area. The indexes have grown massive in size. When I run:

```
GET /_cat/indices?v
```

I can see multiple multi-terabyte indexes. This is costing a lot in AWS fees. The last engineer who worked on this (no longer with the company) left some notes saying the n-gram configuration was causing the index to grow to a massive size. How do I find out information about how n-grams are set up on the index? When I run:

```
GET /my_index/_mapping
```

And get the mapping information I don't see any mention of n-grams for any of the fields. How can I see this information? I can see in the indexer code that it's set up to to have min ngram of 2 and max ngram of 12. Shoudln't this be in the mapping data returned from the call above?

Also, what other analysis can I perform on the indexes to get a better insight into their size, and what can be done to help reduce their footprint.

Thanks.